# Switch problems: No loop, no damaged port, so what?

Tags: switch, cisco-catalyst, networking

This is a medium size company. We have a 2960G switch as a core switch, which is connected to three 2960 series Cisco switches by fibers and clients are connected to these three ones. All of the three switches ports are full, and after a while all network connections fell down. Each time with powering of the lowest switch and turn it on again, we could solve problem temporary. We guessed the lowest switch have some damaged ports, so we replaced it with a 2960 plus new one. Problem still exist and our only solution was the same as before. In third try we use all four switches and share active nodes between them. But nothing changed in to better. We should turn the lowest switch off as well as before. Anyone can help to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Again, you'll need to describe "all network connections fell down" more clearly - loss of link? loss of general network connectivity? loss of Internet connectivity? What do the switches' logs say? Is spanning tree active? How is it configured? We cannot help you without more information. Reposting with no more details won't help.

Comment: "all network connections fell down" means all connections between clients and servers and clients with clients fell down. and in this way loss is belongs to general network connectivity. none of the switches has been configured!

Comment: Without details we can't help you. Without *any* configuration, those switches can be taken over by *anyone* in your network. Mostly likely, what you're experiencing is a broadcast storm caused by a loop on/with the lowest switch which could be mitigated by configuring STP. However, guesswork is off-topic here.